# Problem with registering personalized block styles in wordpress php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, function

WEBSITE ON WORDPRESS

Hey! I am trying to add styling option for a acf gutenberg block I created.
The name of the block is acf/testimonial and it contains one image. When this style is selected, I want the border to be added, otherwise no border.
This what I wrote in functions.php:

```
function register_block_options() {
$inline_css_fade = 
'.right-img {
    border: 3px solid black;
}
.testimonial-img {
    border: 3px solid black;
}';

register_block_style('acf/testimonial', [
    'name' => 'white-fading',
    'label' => __('White Fading', 'txtdomain'),
    'inline_style' => $inline_css_fade
]);
```

};

The problem I get is that no matter what I select (style with border or without) I always see borders on my picture, both in backend and frontend.
The two css class I have point to the same img (the two img just have different class on backend and frontend so I am just telling the code to apply changes to both).

Anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you must apply the most specific edge. How did you get a headache problem ...
I have an effective solution ...

[Use the yellow plugin ...](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yellow-pencil-visual-theme-customizer/)

In your case I would remove everything, since it is in front and behind ...
And install the plugin and create whatever you want in the front, through it ...
No problem ...

And to edit another image (even if it is the same ... On the backend it must have a different name than the frontend ...)
Well placed as 2 integrated systems ...
So separate that too.

Sorry if I got it wrong or out of context ...
Correct me ...
Up until!